# ProgressBar not showing up during a AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to make a simple task in background and show a progress bar while it is being done.

This is the code for the main (and the only) Activity:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        (...)
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity); 
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending data...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        (...)
             // In some onClick Eevent..
             JSONObject result = new Urltasks().execute(...).get();
        (...)

    }
}
```

This is the code for the activity:

```
class Urltasks extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{

    protected void onPreExecute()  {
        System.out.println("Inicia onPreExecute");
        Login.progressDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Login.progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
             // Some work being done. I do not use Login.progressDialog here
    }
}
```

With this code the ProgressDialog shows up when the task ends, and it doesn't dismiss.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here:

```
JSONObject result = new Urltasks().execute(...).get();
```

Calling `get()` on an `AsyncTask` blocks the current thread, i.e. your UI thread, until the AsyncTask is executed. Therefore the progress dialog cannot run. Remove the `get()`.

To obtain the result of the AsyncTask, you can e.g. pass in a listener callback to the asynctask that gets notified when the result is available:

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ParamType, ProgressType, ResultType> {

  private YourResultListener mListener;

  interface YourResultListener {
    void onResultAvailable(ResultType result);
  }

  YourAsyncTask(YourResultListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
  }

  @Override protected ResultType doInBackground(ParamType... params) {
    //...
  }

  @Override protected void onPostExecute(ResultType result) {
    mListener.onResultAvailable(result);
  }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
mProgressDialog.show();
new YourAsyncTask(new YourResultListener() {
    @Override void onResultAvailable(ResultType result) {
      mProgressDialog.dismiss();
      // use result
    }).execute(params);
```

Personally I like to keep user interface elements such as progress dialogs decoupled from async tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your progress dialog in your log in class. Keep it in the async task

this is how you show your dialog

```
     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivityHERE.this, "",
    "Loading... please wait.");
```

Edited this for you:

```
class Urls extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{

ProgressDialog progressDialog;

protected void onPreExecute()  {

     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(yourActivityHERE.this, "",
    "Loading... please wait.");

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   progressDialog.dismiss();
}

protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         // Some work being done. I do not use Login.progressDialog here
}
}
```

Comment: When should I construct it then? In 'OnPreExcute, right? With which Context?

Comment: yes OnPreExcute, and also the the context is the current activity you are in.. I have edited my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

create the constructor in your Urltasks sending the context of the calling class.
then use that context to create the progress dialog in the preExecute of your Urltasks

```
class Urltasks extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{
Context mContext;
public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public UrlTasks(Context c){
   mContext=c;
}
protected void onPreExecute()  {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext); 
    progressDialog.setMessage("Sending data...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         // Do your work here
}
```

}